# fill Na values in df according to other columns values

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr

I would need help in R and deal with columns marging infomations depending on patterns.
In order to undestand here is an exemple :

```
       Groups                    Names   COL1 COL2 COL3
1      G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1   <NA>   10   30
2      G1  KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1  YP_98   NA   NA
3      G1  KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1  YP_99   NA   NA
4      G1  KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1 YP_100   NA   NA
5      G1  KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1 YP_101   NA   NA
6      G1 KB640588.1_2-BICs_-__SP1   <NA>   89   28
7      G1  KB640596.1_38-39_-__SP1 YP_102   NA   NA
8      G1  KB640588.1_38-39_-__SP1 YP_103   NA   NA
9      G1  KB640596.1_21-90_-__SP1 YP_102   NA   NA
10     G1  KB640588.1_78-32_-__SP1 YP_102   NA   NA
11     G1  KB640596.1_89-90_-__SP2 YP_104   90   76
12     G2    LO640571_89-90_-__SP3 YP_100   30   90
13     G2    LO640571_89-90_-__SP3 YP_101   40   10
14     G3    LO640571_89-90_-__SP3   YP_2   29   29
15     G3    LO640571_10-20_-__SP3   YP_2   29   29
16     G3    LO640571_09-99_-__SP3   YP_2   29   29
```

From this df I would like for each Groups and each Names that have a `-BICs` pattern to fill its `COL2` `COL3 values and remplace them to the other Names that 
have the same content part before the first`'_'`

so for instance :

Within the `G1`, only `KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1` has a `-BICs` pattern,
  then I extract the content before the first `'_'` pattern and get : `KB640596.1`
    `KB640596.1` is also present in other Names then I add `COL2` and `COL3` values (`10`   and `30` respectively) to them and get :

```
Groups Names COL1 COL2 COL3
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 NA 10 30
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_98 10 30
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_99 10 30
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_100 10 30
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_101 10 30
G1 KB640588.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 NA 89 28
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_102 10 30
G1 KB640588.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_103 89 28
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_102 10 30
G1 KB640588.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_102 89 28
G1 KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_104 90 76
G2 LO640571_89-90_-__SP3 YP_100 30 90
G2 LO640571_89-90_-__SP3 YP_101 40 10
G3 LO640571_89-90_-__SP3   YP_2   29   29
G3 LO640571_10-20_-__SP3   YP_2   29   29
G3 LO640571_09-99_-__SP3   YP_2   29   29
```

If someone had and idea it would be greate

data

```
   structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3"
), class = "factor"), Names = structure(c(4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("KB640588.1_2-BICs_-__SP1", 
"KB640588.1_38-39_-__SP1", "KB640588.1_78-32_-__SP1", "KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1", 
"KB640596.1_21-90_-__SP1", "KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1", "KB640596.1_38-39_-__SP1", 
"KB640596.1_89-90_-__SP2", "LO640571_09-99_-__SP3", "LO640571_10-20_-__SP3", 
"LO640571_89-90_-__SP3"), class = "factor"), COL1 = structure(c(NA, 
7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("YP_100", 
"YP_101", "YP_102", "YP_103", "YP_104", "YP_2", "YP_98", "YP_99"
), class = "factor"), COL2 = c(10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 89L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 90L, 30L, 40L, 29L, 29L, 29L), COL3 = c(30L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 28L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 76L, 90L, 10L, 29L, 29L, 29L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a new column with row number, `separate` the `Name` column into two columns based on a delimiter (`-`). We can divide the data into two groups, one in which we keep groups with `"BIC"` value in it and another one without it. We `fill` the `COL2`, `COL3` values by group and join the data to get the final dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number())
df2 <- df1 %>%
         separate(Names, paste0('col', 1:2), sep = "-|\\.", extra = "merge") %>%
         group_by(Groups, col1) %>%
         filter(any(grepl('BIC', col2))) %>%
         fill(COL2, COL3) %>%
         mutate(col2 = first(col2)) %>%
         unite(Names, col1, col2, sep = "-")


bind_rows(df2, df1 %>% filter(!row %in% df2$row)) %>%
          arrange(row) %>%
          select(-row)

#   Groups Names                    COL1    COL2  COL3
#   <fct>  <chr>                    <fct>  <int> <int>
# 1 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 NA        10    30
# 2 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_98     10    30
# 3 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_99     10    30
# 4 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_100    10    30
# 5 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_101    10    30
# 6 G1     KB640588-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 NA        89    28
# 7 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_102    10    30
# 8 G1     KB640588-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_103    89    28
# 9 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_102    10    30
#10 G1     KB640588-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_102    89    28
#11 G1     KB640596-1_2-BICs_-__SP1 YP_104    90    76
#12 G2     LO640571_89-90_-__SP3    YP_100    30    90
#13 G2     LO640571_89-90_-__SP3    YP_101    40    10
#14 G3     LO640571_89-90_-__SP3    YP_2      29    29
#15 G3     LO640571_10-20_-__SP3    YP_2      29    29
#16 G3     LO640571_09-99_-__SP3    YP_2      29    29
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems to also change the other values (I want only do the thing for `Names`that have a `-BICs` pattenr in their name because I can have other data such as : `G3 LO640571_89-90_-__SP3 YP_2 29 29` `G3 LO640571_181-10_-__SP3 YP_2 29 29`  `G3 LO640571_2-78_-__SP3 YP_2 29 29`  and in these cases your code seems to change the Names of them (and it should not..) @Ronal Shah i updated the post to show you

Comment: @chippycentra Why row 9 and 11 don't change? They both have `KB640596.1` in them.

Comment: @chippycentra Can you check the updated answer. Does it help?

Comment: Hello, in fact I guess the ```sep = "-|\\."``` does not match all possible cases since I can also have ```contig_97606_2-HSPs_-__sp3_sp``` pattern 'without a ```.```

Comment: I don't exactly remember the context now but `sep = "-|\\."` doesn't mean you need to have both `"-"` and `".'`, it is translated as OR. So any one of them should also work.

Comment: Yes but in the case of ```contig_97606_2-HSPs_-__sp3_sp``` it should be separated as : ```contig_97606``` in one part and ```2-HSPs_-__sp3_sp```in the other part

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'Groups' and the substring of 'Names' based on removing the suffix part, then `mutate` the numeric columns by replacing the NA elements with the corresponding values where the 'Names' have `-BICs`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Groups, grp = str_remove(Names, "_\\d+.*")) %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, ~         
      replace(., is.na(.), .[str_detect(Names, '-BICs')])) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 13 x 5
#   Groups Names                    COL1    COL2  COL3
#   <fct>  <fct>                    <fct>  <int> <int>
# 1 G1     KB640596.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 <NA>      10    30
# 2 G1     KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1  YP_98     10    30
# 3 G1     KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1  YP_99     10    30
# 4 G1     KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1  YP_100    10    30
# 5 G1     KB640596.1_32-33_-__SP1  YP_101    10    30
# 6 G1     KB640588.1_2-BICs_-__SP1 <NA>      89    28
# 7 G1     KB640596.1_38-39_-__SP1  YP_102    10    30
# 8 G1     KB640588.1_38-39_-__SP1  YP_103    89    28
# 9 G1     KB640596.1_21-90_-__SP1  YP_102    10    30
#10 G1     KB640588.1_78-32_-__SP1  YP_102    89    28
#11 G1     KB640596.1_89-90_-__SP2  YP_104    90    76
#12 G2     LO640571_89-90_-__SP3    YP_100    30    90
#13 G2     LO640571_89-90_-__SP3    YP_101    40    10
```

---

Or using `mutate/across`

```
df %>% 
     group_by(Groups, grp = str_remove(Names, "_\\d+.*")) %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~replace(., is.na(.), 
             .[str_detect(Names, '-BICs')]))) %>% 
     ungroup %>%
     select(-grp)
```

Comment: Thanks you but I updated the code in order to illustade that the pattern before the first `_`as its importance. In the new exemple we have 2 different `-BICs`

Comment: Hello, thanks you very much I guess we are close ! :) in fact instead I would like to change the Names values in order that they have the same Names value as the one with the pattern  `_` that gave the COL2 and COL3 values (check the expected outptut the Names values chanded.